# What is the difference between putFile() and putStream() methods of StorageReference of Firebase cloud storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload files to the Firebase cloud storage. I found that there are two different methods that I can use, which are `StorageReference.putFile()` and `StorageReference.putStream()` . I am confused on what is the difference between these two methods.

PS: I do not even know the difference between stream and file.

Comment: This is a bit too broad for this site. One method takes a File URI and the other takes a Stream. A discussion of how these related and how they are used is not appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that these are overloded methods and are using different parameters. There are three flavours of `putFile()` method:

> 1. putFile(Uri uri, StorageMetadata metadata, Uri existingUploadUri)
> 2. putFile(Uri uri, StorageMetadata metadata)
> 3. putFile(Uri uri)

While `putStream()` method has only two flavours:

> 1. putStream(InputStream stream, StorageMetadata metadata)
> 2. putStream(InputStream stream)

All these methods do the same, asynchronously uploads from a content URI to this StorageReference and all three return [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask).

Comment: What about memory consumption and performances ? Or is it too hard to see any differences ?

Comment: @TommyD I never benchmarked them, but if you are curious, give it a try.

Comment: i will challenge the size of the File and the InputStream, and the memory usage during upload. The upload itself should not be very different
Thanks for the answer